# Spring Data MongoDB check if field exist then query

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

If I want to check if a date falls between a date range. I can do something like this.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("effectiveFrom").lte(date),
       Criteria.where("validTill").gte(date)));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, DocumentClass.class, "DocumentName");
```

But suppose the `validTill` does exist in some cases, what is the most convenient way to do this. So it should be something like check if `validTill` exists then compare the given date within the date range otherwise just find the records where `effectiveFrom` is less than or equals to the given date.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-query.criteria Look at exists. If validTill exists and if validTill greater than date.

Answer (score 3):

Adding This should work:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("validTill").exists(true));
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("effectiveFrom").lte(date),
       Criteria.where("validTill").gte(date)));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, DocumentClass.class, "DocumentName");
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the orOperator in query specifying both the conditions that you have in your question.One would consist of both dates as you already have and other will have

```
Criteria.where("effectiveFrom").lte(date),Criteria.where("validTill").exists(false))
```

This would at least insure that you do not lose any data.

Comment: query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator
                (new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("effectiveFrom").lte(date),Criteria.where("validTill").gte(date)),
                new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("effectiveFrom").lte(date),Criteria.where("validTill").exists(false))
                ));.......Try this if it works